# Is there a need to further normalize this data?

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I need to normalize some data and have reached the 2nd normalization stage. I'm not sure whether I can further normalize this data to 3rd NF as I cannot spot any partial dependencies.

What do I do next?

[image: Normalization]

Comment: What reference you were given for normalizaiton? 2nf is when there are no partial dependencies of non-prime attributes on candidate keys. 3nf is when 2nf and no non-prime attribute is transitively dependent on candidate keys. So you seem confused about 2nf & 3nf. Anyway one cannot normalize without all functional dependencies, but you didn't give them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forward with the 3NF as far as your data fits the rules for the 1st and 2nd NF even if you haven´t changed anything to reach this NF

Comment: So i can use the 2nd NF as the 3rd NF?

Comment: As far as all conditions of he 1NF and 2NF are fullfilled, you can go on with the 3NF, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @FutureProgrammer & Michael Except that eliminating certain partial dependencies is for getting to 2nf, not for getting to 3nf from 2nf.

Comment: @philipxy I have reached 2nd NF but have no partial dependencies (Which is needed to go to 3rd NF) which is why I was asking if its possible to go to 3rd NF, or do I just copy the same data from 2nd NF for 3rd NF seeing as I cannot normalize it any further.

Comment: @FutureProgrammer It's very hard to understand you. If you have shown that the relation is in 2nf then it is *because* there are no partial FDs (of a certain kind). To also be in 3nf you must also have no *transitive* FDs (of a certain kind). But you haven't given any FDs so why do you think you know the CKs or that you know anything about what NFs this satisfies?